# Account kit: Set the default language for iOS app

Tags: ios, account-kit

How to change the language in `Facebook-Account-Kit` for iOS?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Facebook said that: Localization support is also provided by the SDK. The supported languages are packaged with the SDK. You don't need anything else to display text in the appropriate locale.
But it's not enough, you must add your language in Project Info like image below[image]

Answer (score 0):

I just change the simulator/device language. The display language on AccountKIT UI will be changed automatically . It worked for me

I also don't need to add localization config as "Thành Ngô Văn" answer

Answer (score 0):

I had changed the device language. Now working fine.